# API Platform, how to use Security as a filter on GET Collections?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm doing my security on my entity this way:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *       "post"={
 *           "security_post_denormalize"="is_granted('MESSAGE_CREATE', object)"
 *       },
 *       "get"={
 *           "security"="is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER')"
 *       }
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *        "get"={
 *            "security"="is_granted('MESSAGE_VIEW', object)"
 *        },
 *        "patch"={
 *          "security"="is_granted('MESSAGE_EDIT', object)"
 *        },
 *        "delete"={
 *            "security"="is_granted('MESSAGE_DELETE', object)"
 *        },
 *        "put"={
 *            "security"="is_granted('MESSAGE_REPLACE', object)"
 *        }
 *     }
 * )
```

And was curious to know if there is a way to do on the collectionOperations a filter to make sure that the user has `MESSAGE_VIEW` on each items in my collection instead of doing `is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER')`. I am aware that DataProvider exists, but these are aggressive as I would have to rebuild the filters manually... I've seen that I was able using the security_post_denormalize for POST and it worked well, but couldn't find a solution for the "GET" collection part. Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I do agree, Dataprovider are agressive. you could do it by using a service . You could inject the security layer to remove entries from your collection. I didn't like this solution. It use a lot of resources without (and with) a good cache layer.

But with an extension, you could do it to customize the generated DQL. You don't have to add a cache because Doctrine will do it for you. [Extensions](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#custom-doctrine-orm-extension) are services, so you can inject the security layer and everything else needed.

It seems that it works for Doctrine and Elastic Search and MongoDB too. The Api-Platform documentation contains [a short paragraph about it](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/#filtering-collection-according-to-the-current-user-permissions):

> Filtering collections according to the role or permissions of the
> current user must be done directly at the state provider level. For
> instance, when using the built-in adapters for Doctrine ORM, MongoDB
> and ElasticSearch, removing entries from a collection should be done
> using extensions. Extensions allow to customize the generated
> DQL/Mongo/Elastic/... query used to retrieve the collection (e.g. add
> WHERE clauses depending of the currently connected user) instead of
> using access control expressions. As extensions are services, you can
> inject the Symfony Security class into them to access to current
> user's roles and permissions.

In the ApiPlatform documentation, [there is another example](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#example) to filter and retrieve only "the offers of the current user". It isn't so different from your problem. You should have a look on it, you will see the injected security layer. It will help you to create your own extensions.

Comment: Extensions seems to be the solution indeed, but I don't have any SQL to add to my queries, I already have the logic in my isGranted('MESSAGE_VIEW', $message)... In a perfect world, what I'm trying to achieve is one service over all my entities that would just get the entity name, make it UPPERCASE + _VIEW and then this service would work for my entire application without specific SQL for each one... I'm thinking my best way is DataProvider and apply filters re-code the parts that deals with filters so it keeps working...

Comment: All the logic is different for each entity, and the Voters are already perfectly configurated and tested for each entity, it seems extreme to me to replicate that logic in SQL to filter out each elements. Anyways, I'll try to think of something using extension and post my response here

Answer (score 0):

In api platform documetation i found this solution :
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/#filtering-collection-according-to-the-current-user-permissions

> Filtering collections according to the role or permissions of the current user must be done directly at the state provider level. For instance, when using the built-in adapters for Doctrine ORM, MongoDB and ElasticSearch, removing entries from a collection should be done using extensions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).